# How to override Function.prototype.toString

Tags: javascript

I have an requirement where I need to return `function start <function code> function end` to be the output of toString function get invoked on any function.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? Post an example of any function and desired output of its toString method.

Comment: So does `Function.prototype.toString=function(){ return 'function start function end';}`  do what you want?  If not, why not?  What fo you want it to do instead?  Provide a specific example and the desired result. Please use edit to edit your post and elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would output function start and function end wrapped around the source code of the function's source itself. If you don't want the source, simply remove it.

```
(function(){
    var j=Function.prototype.toString;//copy of native toString;
    Function.prototype.toString=function()
    {
        return '//function start\n'+j.call(this)+'\n//function end';
    };
})();

testy=function(a,b)
{
    return a+b;
};

alert(testy);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx5L4qqk/